# ASP.net - Add multiple rows based on a textbox value

Tags: asp.net, row

I’m trying to figure out the best way to add multiple rows into an existing SQL table using `ASP.NET`. I'm new to VBA programming so am a little lost and need some help with this problem.

Example, the user will enter.

2 (LotNo) 
5 (itemNo) – Add multiple rows depending on this value. 
100 (cartNo) 
20120202 (Date)

Result: 
2, 1, 100, 20120202
2, 2, 100, 20120202
2, 3, 100, 20120202
2, 4, 100, 20120202
2, 5, 100, 20120202

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is a bit vague. Please provide more details so we can fully understand the problem. I don't understand how you get the result from the input.

Comment: You mention both VBA and ASP.NET in our question. Is this an oversight?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `Table Value Parameter`

```
Dim sc As New SqlCommand(
  "INSERT INTO MyNewTable (field1, field2,...)"&
    "SELECT field1, field2,... FROM @MyTable;", connection) 
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyTable", MyTable)  
sc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx